# In my Wordpress theme, how can I add pagination for the blog page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I've currently set Wordpress to only show the latest 5 posts in the blog page.
It works correctly and the post excerpts are being shown as desired.

Only problem is, the 6th post is not shown at all and pagination is not added.
I need a 'Previous/Next' system to show the other pages but couldn't find how to implement it anywhere.

Current theme code:

```
<?php 
    if (is_page()) {
        the_content();  
    }
    if (is_front_page()) {
        the_content();  
    }
    if ((is_single())) {
        echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'; echo the_permalink(); echo'" title="'; the_title(); echo '">'; the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</h2>';
        echo '<h6>'; the_excerpt(); '</h6>';
    }
    if ((is_home())) {
        echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'; echo the_permalink(); echo'" title="';         the_title(); echo '">'; the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</h2>';
        echo '<h6>'; the_excerpt(); '</h6>';
        echo '<h4>'; 
        echo '<a href="'; echo the_permalink();  echo '">';
        echo '<img src="'; bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); echo '/images/read_more.gif"         alt="Read more..." border="0" />';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</h4>';
        echo '<hr />';
    }
?>        
<?php  ?>                 
</div>
<div class="body-bottom"></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: <div class="navigation">
   <div class="alignleft"><? next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?>
   </div>
   <div class="alignright"><? previous_posts_link('Next &raquo;') ?>
   </div>
   </div>

is what I added to implement the navigation, works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin is also useful for paging.

http://www.devdevote.com/cms/wordpress-plugins/wp-paging

you can also use wordpress default paging code:

Answer (score 1):

For Pagination u can use plugin NAME WP-PageNavi plugin.
Plugin Url :- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/